# Message inbox full of read messages is very dark and out of place

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, global-inbox

Apparently, we got a new inbox recently.

Now, "read" notifications are literally grayed-out, making the entire box gray.
This feels completely out of place, it's the darkest element on the page (on Meta and light mode SO):

> [image]

I'd prefer it to have some opacity, for example:

> [image]

Comment: Assumed this was a bug of some kind. I'm not a UI expert at all but I can't see how this is an improvement over what we had before.

Comment: Well, you can now mark read messages as unread, so that's better :D

Comment: Since [the accessibility project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382079/241919), I kind of doubt they will make it lighter using opacity than the current greyed-out ignored questions...

Comment: Well, instead of opacity, they can just use a lighter colour :D Jokes aside, anything but as dark as it is now seems preferable to me.

Comment: Wheres SamuelLiew? We need a user script! :)

Comment: I've added this as feedback on the announcement: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384238/203057

Comment: Yep, same as [what happened with ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382047/348196). As Laurel said there, they just make changes that might be slightly more accessible to one group of users while destroying the user experience for other users. That's not a good solution and that's not how accessibility works.

Comment: I disagree. The new design is better; and it's not actually the darkest element on the page.

Comment: @pigrammer please don't state your opinion as fact ("The new design is better"). Now, what elements are darker? Buttons? Input elements are not exactly comparable to page blocks like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus the "I disagree" part already sets the stage for it being a personal opinion. Not sure if you are going to see this response since it is almost invisible in your inbox.

Comment: I read that as him disagreeing with my preference, with as reason the "fact" that the new design is better, @Gimby. It's always better to err on the side of caution when writing: _"I think it looks better"_ is clearly an opinion :D